# Is it possible to connect to a postgresql DB and load a postgresql table to a sparkDataFrame from Databricks notebook

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to connect to postgresql DB available in on-prem subscription to my Azure Databricks notebook(cloud subscription) and load a postgresql table to a sparkDataFrame, please let me know if anybody has worked on it, i know i can run the below pyspark code to read the data from a table but need help on how to establish a connection from my Azure Databricks notebook to postgresql DB available in on-prem subscription.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/path_to_postgresDriver/postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename") \
    .option("dbtable", "tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()
```

Comment: What is your issue? Have you tried?

Comment: please post error that you see, and check firewall rules